# Using widetext.sty, keep unbalanced columns on last page

Tags: two-column

I use the `twocolumn` option for more compact layout and better placement of my typically small figures. For some parts I additionally need the `widetext` package and the command with the same name.

However for some purposes I *also* prefer keeping the columns un-balanced on the last page, but when using the `widetext` package they automatically become balanced.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is caused by the `widetext` package invoking the `\flushend` command from the `flushend` package.

In order to make columns on the last page unbalanced again, put `\raggedend` (also from the `flushend` package) before `\end{document}`.

A minimum example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage{widetext}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\raggedend
\end{document}
```